# PDF reader to read through a folder of PDFs and return a numpy array for keywords for each file read

Tags: python, numpy, pdf, pypdf

I have a script that can find and read a singular pdf file and return the count of a specific word that is in that pdf file. I would like to expand this scrip so that it will read all pdf files in the specific folder and create a table (numpy array) with the name of the pdf as the the rows and the specific words as the columns - a count of each word for the respective pdf file in the corresponding cells.

Below is the code that can get me to the point of counting a specific word for a singular file:

```
import PyPDF2 
import textract
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nummpy as np


#path and singular object. something of a forloop and and list made to parse through all files in the folder?
filename = rb'path'
pdfFileObj = open(filename, 'rb')

pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
count = 0
text = ""

while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()

if text != "":
   text = text
else:
   text = textract.process(fileurl, method='tesseract', language='eng')

tokens = word_tokenize(text)
punctuations = ['(',')',';',':','[',']',',']
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
keywords = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words and not word in punctuations]

#count the specific word. want to count many words and the place them into an array match to the particular pdf as explained in first part. 
keywords.count('metaphysics')
```

Getting into this as a hobby and this is one of most intricate things I have tried to create

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

arr=np.array([])
path='C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/'

for entry in os.listdir(path):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, entry)):
        if entry.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            filename=entry 
            #followed by ur code
            #....
            keywords=np.array(keywords)
            arr=np.concatenate((arr,keywords))
```

Comment: when I run this it gives the error: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'East and West.pdf'" - which is the first pdf file in the folder. So it has the correct directory and begins to parse accordingly, but stops on the first pdf file in said directory.

Comment: try **filename=os.path.join(path,entry)**

Comment: helped to get past that issue, now am getting an issue: "NameError: name 'fileurl' is not defined" which refers to the else portion in the while loop.                               
                                                                                                                                This if statement exists to check if the above library returned words. It's done because PyPDF2 cannot read scanned file...if it returns false it runs hte OCR library textract to convert scanned/image based PDF files into text.

Comment: here is the documentation for the specific function: https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python_package.html

Comment: text = textract.process(**filename**, method='tesseract', language='eng')

Comment: Change else as i mentioned and try

Comment: Now runs into whole new error (a rabbit hole from my initial resarch) of: "ShellError: The command `pdftoppm C:\Users\filepathEast and West.pdf C:\Users\maxwe\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpve9qcx9f\conv` failed with exit code 127
------------- stdout -------------
------------- stderr -------------"

Looks to be something with a package called "poppler" and running that in the path. Seems that people have a lot of issues with this....